# Responsive images different sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive, image-scaling

I've tried searching for this, but could not find a close enough issue.
I have a responsive web site, that looks great on a PC, but on mobile, the images of the gallery are all different sizes. The actual images are all identical sizes, but mobile seems to make them grow as they go. Tested on Android and iPhone.
Screenshots:
[Site on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91lXL.jpg)
[Site on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34RjJ.jpg) & [Site on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r9d8.jpg)
The image codes are thus:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #primary { width:100%; }
    #secondary { width:100%; margin:0; border:none; }
}
img { max-width: 100%; height: 100%; }
@media (min-device-width:600px) {
    img[data-src-600px] {
        content: attr(data-src-600px, url);
    }
}

@media (min-device-width:800px) {
    img[data-src-800px] {
        content: attr(data-src-800px, url);
    }
}
```

```html
<tr><td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Bridal_Shoot/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="/images/weddings/Bridal_Shoot.jpg" alt="Click on image to open gallery" width="235" height="352" class="z-depth-2 rounded-circle img-fluid"/><BR>Bridal Shoot</a></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Butler_Wedding/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="/images/weddings/Butler_Wedding.jpg" alt="Click on image to open gallery" width="235" height="352" class="z-depth-2 rounded-circle img-fluid"/><BR>Butler Wedding</a></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Engagement_Session/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="/images/weddings/Engagement_Session.jpg" alt="Click on image to open gallery" width="235" height="352" class="z-depth-2 rounded-circle img-fluid"/><BR>Engagement Session</a></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Fluke–Chenault_Wedding/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="/images/weddings/Fluke–Chenault_Wedding.jpg" alt="Click on image to open gallery" width="235" height="352" class="z-depth-2 rounded-circle img-fluid"/><BR>Fluke–Chenault Wedding</a></td></tr>
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be great. (I've tried using Bootstrap, but it made other images used on the page distorted).

Comment: Please take this as kindly as possible, but using a HTML `<table>` for layout (a practice which was beginning to be recognised as outdated as long ago as 20 years ago) means that you definitely don't have _a responsive web site_. A responsive web site would (for example) enable your 4x2 layout on desktop to become, effortlessly, a 2x4 layout on a tablet and 1x8 layout on a touchphone. I recognise that this doesn't help your current situation, I merely wished to point out that the markup you have at present, doesn't fall under any known definition of _responsive_. [1/2]

Comment: To achieve _responsive_ you will use CSS features like `@media` queries (as you have done above) but also (importantly) approaches like [_CSS Flexbox_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [_CSS Grid_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids), CSS units like [`%`, `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` & `vmax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units) and CSS properties like [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio). [2/2]

Comment: Yes, I knew I'd get comments about my table, TR & TD's. I'm old school, and haven't dabbled in coding in years (I know, it shows LOL), so this is all a new learning experience for me. I'm learning all this new stuff as I go. I got the site  responsive, all but those gallery pics, and there's 7 galleries in total that this affects.  I was a t a loss trying to fix it. I guess I should start over, with newer coding and more CSS (Which I'm slowly learning as well)

Comment: No worries, @JamesPike - my point was not so much focused on layout tables but simply observing that you can a) use a layout table on a web page; or you can b) make a web page responsive and describe it as responsive. But you cannot use a layout table on a web page and then describe the page as responsive. The former contradicts the latter - like a silent noise or an opaque transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a **responsive layout** for the elements included in your question.

Please note - this is just *an example* of what you can do with CSS responsive features, properties and units.

I have included a `@media` query which reduces the number of columns from 4 to 2 at a breakpoint of `600px`.

To demonstrate an array of what's possible I have also used responsive units:

- `%`
- `vw`

a responsive property:

- `aspect-ratio`

a responsive display:

- `display: flex`

and a responsive function:

- `min()`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: min(100%, 960px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery-link {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 22%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: min(16px, 3vw);
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.gallery-figure {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 235/352;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .gallery-link {
    flex: 0 0 44%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Bridal_Shoot/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Bridal_Shoot.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Bridal Shoot" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Bridal Shoot</figcaption>
  </a>

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Butler_Wedding/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Butler_Wedding.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Butler Wedding" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Butler Wedding</figcaption>
  </a>

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Engagement_Session/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Engagement_Session.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Engagement Session" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Engagement Session</figcaption>
  </a>

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Fluke–Chenault_Wedding/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Fluke–Chenault_Wedding.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Fluke–Chenault Wedding" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Fluke–Chenault Wedding</figcaption>
  </a>

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Bridal_Shoot/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Bridal_Shoot.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Bridal Shoot" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Bridal Shoot</figcaption>
  </a>

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Butler_Wedding/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Butler_Wedding.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Butler Wedding" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Butler Wedding</figcaption>
  </a>

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Engagement_Session/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Engagement_Session.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Engagement Session" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Engagement Session</figcaption>
  </a>

  <a class="gallery-link" href="/Portfolio/Weddings/Fluke–Chenault_Wedding/index.html" target="_blank">
    <figure class="gallery-figure">
      <img class="gallery-image" src="/images/weddings/Fluke–Chenault_Wedding.jpg" title="Click on image to open gallery" alt="Fluke–Chenault Wedding" />
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Fluke–Chenault Wedding</figcaption>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: So I tried this, but it made the entire page unresponsive. It enlarged all the pictures to roughly 200% of their original sizes (on PC, tablet and phone) and you had to scroll the page left and right, which is not what I was looking to do. I already had the page showing correctly on all devices, minus the gallery images changing sizes. Thank you though.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, so I need to clarify: I wrote in my explanation above: _"Please note - this is just an example of what you can do with CSS responsive features, properties and units."_ I think you have taken the example above as a literal solution that you can drop into your own website. It's not supposed to be that - instead, I am giving you examples of CSS responsive functions, units, properties and displays, so that you can put together your own responsive solution. Please view the above as a "serving suggestion" - as a starting point for your own solution. Thanks.

Comment: It may help you a lot to read up on and practise CSS `%` and responsive CSS units like `vw` and `vmin` / `vmax` and possibly even `rem`. See: [Relative Units in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units)

Comment: I saw that it was an example, and made changes where needed. As far as I could tell, the main thing I needed to alter was the .gallery-image. I definitely need to try and study up on all this CSS. Thanks for your help @Rounin.

Comment: You're very much welcome, James. As you see, CSS has come on in leaps and bounds since the 2000s - and no small amount of sophistication has arrived in the last 5-6 years. I promise you that time you invest in CSS will repay itself threefold. It is a superbly clever and wonderful little technology. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
https://youtu.be/tmWvwp3rpso
```

Please check above the link, you will get the solutions for the image responsive and also check the border-radius property for circle image

Comment: You missed my comment about already trying Bootstrap, but it messed with the other images on the site that didn't need changing. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well with w: 100% i h: 100% you told your image to scale max w and h on container, just use width: 100%. I use always some container than put img inside as background so i use backgroun-position and background-size: cover; after that you manipulate just with container width and height, and with background-positon you target what part of image you want to show if img is too big for mobile , you can also use transform : scale to zoom in

Comment: I originally only had the 100% width variable. But in trying to fix this problem, I tried 100% height to see if that would make them all the same height... but it didn't, and I just forgot to remove that variable.